# One Domain - Two Stores - Magento

Tags: magento

I have Magento installed on my server.

My client would like to host 2 'Stores' on the same domain.

Each 'Store' would have different Products within it.

Should I create 2 separate Store 'Views' or 2 separate Stores? Or perhaps just create 2 categories with the Store Name for each?

Thanks for any pointers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I created 2 Stores and 2 Root Categories (Store A & Store B).

I also followed this tutorial: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/3_-_store_setup_and_management/catalog/creating_and_assigning_root_categories

Hopefully this was useful to someone :-)